# Absorbing Element is a Unit

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing, proof-verification

Show that an absorbing element of a monoid is a unit if and only if it is the only element.

This is an if and only if proof so that means I have to prove it both ways: A implies B and B implies A.

I have an attempt at A implies B but I'm not sure how to approach B implies A. Any advice or critiques would be great!! Thanks.

A implies B:
Let x be an absorbing element such that x $\in$ S where S is a monoid. Suppose x is a unit, which is an invertible element. All monoids are semigroups and semigroups can only have one absorbing element and x is an absorbing element so it is the only element in S.

B implies A:
Suppose x is the only element in S.

Comment: I prefer to state the theorem this way: "In every nonzero monoid, all absorbing elements are uninvertible."

Answer (score 1):

B $\to$ A is true in general: by definition of monoid there exists $e \in S$ such that $e$ is the (well.. you have to prove that it is unique) identity of $S$. Consequently, if $x$ is the only element of $S$, we must have $x = e$.

Comment: Can you just say that $e$ is the unique identity of S because of the definition of a semigroup. All monoids are semigroups and semigroups can only have one identity and one absorbing element. Therefore, the identity element, $e$ is unique.

Comment: @user2553807 The identity element is unique for every magma (if it exists), associativity is not needed. Actually $B \to A$ is true for any magma: if $x \in S$ is the only element, then we must have $x \circ x = x$ and thus $x$ is trivially a unit.

Answer (score 0):

As for $A\to B$, what you proved is that your absorbing $x\in S$ is the only *absorbing* element of $S$, whereas what you needed to show is that $S=\lbrace x \rbrace$. This isn't too difficult, try starting by showing that if $x$ is both invertible and a unit then it follows that $x=e$ (where $e\in S$ is the unit element).

Comment: Do you actually have to 'show' any of that or can you just assume that x is invertible and any invertible element is automatically a unit?

Comment: I think one of us is confusing two notions here (and it could very well be me). I'm not very familiar with the terminology of monoid theory, but I know that in ring theory the set of units is the set of invertible elements, whereas there is a distinguished *unit element*, which is the unique element $e\in S$ such that $ex=xe=x$ for any $x\in S$.